# Check if an array of substrings all exist in an array of strings

Tags: python, arrays, loops, iterator, substring

I've got a bit of a complicated question (for my limited Python knowledge) around iterating through and checking an array for any missing values.

I have an array of key strings and I need to check the array contains all substrings in another array. If it doesn't, I need to output which are missing.

Example:

```
array1 = ['key/value/one123904', 'key/value/two342389', 'key/value/three234093']
array2 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

My ideal output would be to say all elements of `array2` exist in `array1` if they do, or else in the example above, to output `No key for value: four`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by iterating over your list of substrings, `array2`, and test whether [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) of the key strings in `array1` contain this substring, i.e.:

```
for string in array2:
    if not any(string in key_string for key_string in array1):
        print("No key for value: " + string)
        break                                                                   
else:                                                                           
    print("All elements of array2 exist in array1")
```

In case you're not familiar with the `else` clause of `for`, this will be executed only when the loop exits normally, i.e. will not execute if `break` is used to terminate the loop early.

If you wanted to record all of the substrings which were not present:

```
missing = [string for string in array2                                          
           if not any(string in ks for ks in array1)]                           
if missing:                                                                     
    for string in missing:                                                      
        print("No key for value: " + string)                                    
else:                                                                           
    print("All elements of array2 exist in array1")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the method i was able to make for your question,

```
def missing(arr1, arr2):
    #arr1 is the array of strings to be searched
    #arr2 is the array of substrings
    notFound=""
    for i in arr2: # i = each element in array 2
        for j in arr1: # j = each element in array 1
            if i in j: # if substring of i is in an element in j
                break # moves onto next element in the array
            elif j == arr1[-1]: # if not found in the string, checks if  on the last item in the array.
                notFound = notFound+" "+i
    if notFound != "":
        print("No key for value:", notFound)
    else:
        print("all elements of array2 exist in array1")
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
print(
    "No key for value(s): {}".format(
        " ".join([k for k in array2 if not any(k in v for v in array1) ])
    )
)
```

Or if you want to handle more properly the case of all values being present

```
no_match = [k for k in array2 if not any(k in v for v in array1) ]
print(
    "No key for value(s): {}".format(" ".join(no_match))
    if no_match
    else "All keys have values"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array1 = ['key/value/one123904', 'key/value/two342389', 'key/value/three234093']
array2 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']


def does_match_in_array_of_string(key: str, search_list : list) -> bool:
    for item in search_list:
        if key in item:
            return True
    return False;


match_failures = [key for key in array2 if not does_match_in_array_of_string(key, array1)]

if len(match_failures):
    print(f'No key for values: {match_failures}')
else:
    print('All keys have values')
```

Comment: I'm curious if anyone can find a reasonable way to do it with filter()

Comment: Depends on how you define *reasonable*?

Comment: My quick attempt was gross and far from any human definition of reasonable :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sum_array1 =""
for string1 in array1:
    sum_array1 = sum_array1 + string1 + ","
missing = [string2 for string2 in array2 if string2 not in sum_array1]
if missing:                                                                     
    for string in missing:                                                      
        print("No key for value: " + string)                                    
else:                                                                           
    print("All elements of array2 exist in array1")
```